# keycloak Spring Security : Unable to login with Bearer token as null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I have integrated the Keylock with Spring boot using @KeycloakConfiguration in SecurityConfig Class,

```
@KeycloakConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    // configureGlobal() tasks the SimpleAuthorityMapper to make sure roles are not
    // prefixed with ROLE_.
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    // keycloakConfigResolver defines that we want to use the Spring Boot properties
    // file support instead of the default keycloak.json.
    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    // we are permitting all here but we are gonna have method level
    // pre-authorization
    
      @Override protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      super.configure(http); http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
      .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin**").hasAnyRole("admin")
      .anyRequest().permitAll();
      
      }
     
    
    // we configure to accepts CORS requests from all and any domains
        @Bean
        public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
            return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
                @Override
                public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                    registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE");
                }
            };
        }
        
    




@PostMapping("/login")
    public @ResponseBody  AuthToken login(@RequestBody LoginForm form) {
        
          Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities =
          (Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority>) SecurityContextHolder
          .getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();       
          
          AuthToken authToken = authService.login(form);
          authToken.setAuthorities(authorities);
          return authToken;
         

    }
```

and I am able to log in without a Bearer token and with an empty Bearer token.
[image]
I have created a login page in angular,
and from that, I am passing the bearer token is null.
[image]

I am getting

status": 401,
“error”: “Unauthorized”

and there are no security logs on eclipse.

[image]

Thanks and Regards

Comment: pleaase post your full spring security debug logs

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the log,
@Toerktumlare.    there are no logs on the console

Comment: please dont post images of code/logs as it is not allowed... and also, all you see is INFO logs, i asked for the DEBUG log, you need to enable debug logging, please learn how to debug spring applications before asking on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Put this into SecurityConfig

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring()
            // All of Spring Security will ignore the requests
            .antMatchers("/login");
}
```